# What is the difference between an embedded system and dedicated system?

Tags: terminology

To my understanding,

a dedicated system is a computer system capable of performing 1 specific task
an embedded system is a computer system within a larger system that performs a specific task

Is there a difference that i'm missing or is dedicated system just a more generic term for referring to things like 'file server'.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, please rephrase it.

Comment: Seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 2):

An embedded system is embedded in some larger device/system. For example, a computer used to control a car is embedded, or the microprocessor controlling e.g. a washing machine.

A dedicated system is one which is used for one task only, like file serving or running a database.

Most embedded systems are dedicated (to their specific task(s)). There isn't a clear cut definition.

Answer (score -2):

An embedded system, is like a microprocessor, not to be confused with a CPU. It requires no extra software to work.